# LotusScript C callout broken in Domino 11 on AIX 64 bit

Tags: lotus-domino, aix, lotusscript, hcl

Since upgrading from Domino 9 to 11 some LS-Agents crash the server on calls to C API functions.
We're running Domino 11.0.1 64 bit on AIX 7.2
First we thought about a change in handle sizes and switching from 32 bit to 64 bit fixed some calls. But other calls needed a switch from 32 bit to 16 bit to work. Strange! (In fact the declared size should make no difference, as long as its big enough for the actual value, because all arguments are passed as 64 bit on 64 bit machines - at least in this case)

I've tested the calls from Java using JNA - everything works as expected with 32 bit handles. So C API seems to be OK, but LS C callout seems broken.

Does anyone else notice this behaviour? Or is it just us?

Comment: You need to show your code, identify the specific API calls that are failing, and show the stacktrace generated by the server crash,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue:
SPR #ASHEBSVQ72 (not online visible by now)
It's a regression bug with C callouts from LS on AIX. Has been there since Domino 10. Strange thing nobody but us ran into this problem.
No easy workaround known. Wait for a fix or use JNA in Java for callouts.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in 11.0.1FP3